# Shortcut key for Pasting Image as Object?

Tags: microsoft-word, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a shortcut key for pasting image as object, in Microsoft Word 2013 ?

I tried to paste the copied image, it paste as whole image. Rather I want it as object. Just like when you use `Insert -> Object -> Create from File -> Display link as Icon`

I tried paste special, but nothing is there.

Well, Shortcut from the ribbon is <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> and choose the image file.

Is there any simple process ? I'm intended to paste lot of images in this way.

Answer (score 0):

We can do the following steps to custom Shortcut for Insert Object setting:

1. In Word 2013, click **File** > **Options** > **Customize Ribbon**.
2. Next to Keyboard shortcuts, click **Customize**.
3. In the **Categories** list, select **Insert Tab**.
4. Under **Commands** list, select **InsertObject**.
5. In keyboard, press the shotcut keys you want to use. I set it to **Ctrl+L** in my testing. [image]
6. Click **Assign** > **Close** > **OK**.

Then you can press Ctrl+L to open Insert Object window.